# EVSE method of monitoring PE line in aCcordance with IEC 62955

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, safety

I would need some opinions/help regarding if my circuit is acceptable for its purpose.
In order to meet strict safety criteria, my circuit needs to be able to detect if there is high voltage present on the grounding line (from an external source) and disconnect the grounding if that is the case. The circuit also needs to detect if there is a short between phase(L) and grounding(PE). Additionaly i can not connect any element in serial of the PE line, since its resistence needs to be lower then 700mohm.

My currrent idea is to use an optocoupler to detect voltage between the PE line and N line. The optocoupler has 2 emmiter diodes for ac currents (like i have drawn)[image: the schematic of the optocoupler]

The output of the optocoupler is then connected to the microcontroler, which controls a relay that dissconects the PE line in case of current or high voltage on it. The relay is NC type, so it always connects the PE line even while the power is off.

For the current detection, the device will already be connected behind a type A circuit breaker, and additionaly have a residual current detector built in (N4641-X900), that can detect 6mA DC and 30 mA AC currents with a fluxgate coil around L and N lines[image: the differential current sensor]

Is this the correct way to meet safety criteria? Any input would be highly aprechiated since i have never designed any safety compliant circuits.

This is a crude concept i had for the safety schematic
[image: a crude concept schematic]

Comment: What is the opto achieving if both sides are using iso gnd?

Comment: My guess was for there to be a current through the resisitor if there is a high voltage on the PE line. Would it be better if the opto would be connected between PE and N ? In that case should i also lower the resistor to something like 10k?

Comment: This is a very strange requirement so maybe you have misinterpreted a specification. Trying to measure a voltage difference between two isolated parts is fraught with problems.

Comment: "if there is high voltage pre if there is high voltage present on the grounding line sent on the grounding line" Voltage on grounding line relative to what?

Comment: Just to clarify, these are requirements for an electric car charger. if there  is external voltage on the grounding line, it can shock the user if he touces the chassis of the car. thats why it needs to detect voltage on it. presumable the voltage between ground and neutral, since those are usually 0V?

Comment: You probably misinterpreted some details, but one is for sure the PE may not be disconnected in any way.

Comment: This seems very strange to me, since the requirements for certification clearly state that they will be testing the response in case of an external voltage on PE from the input side. In that case the entire circuit and the PE line need to disconnect, to prevent a person from touching the energized chassis, do they not?

Comment: In that case you should edit the question and describe the used standards for this EV charger, some sketch regarding of charger type DC/AC voltages, currents, isolation transformers and only then ask. The image you posted is blurry, no description on what these blocks are and where the vehicle is. A PE circuit is something really serious and you can't disconnect it by measuring with an optocoupler that shares the same GND point - it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

First, if the PE has to be disconnected, then also the power has to be disconnected at the same time. In order to find if your car has a leaky connection from the battery to the chassis you have to measure that before connecting the power and PE, first.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foLhoN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Eval board tester from TI](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-01513)

[image]